# Number of socket clients connected to server

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I have a NIO TCP server which accepts and reads data from clients. I would like to know the **count number of clients connected** at regular intervals, for monitoring purpose (**like netstat or lsof**) in **java**. Is there any way to achieve this without maintaining a counter and increment it every time a client connects?

Something like:

```
int clientsConnected = serverSocket.getClientsConnected();
```

Comment: No, you have to count them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that I can think of, you would just have to have a variable called `count` and increment it each and every time.

```
int count = 0;
server.accept(); 
count++;
```

Comment: And decrement it every time you close an accepted socket.

Comment: Yes that too. Not a hard concept obviously.