# Run some specific code in Server when there are 3 clients connected to server in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

```
if(clientCount == 3) {
```

that's the problem in client class 
I am using if statement but that only work for 3rd client but not for 1st and 2nd client as for them clientCount is not equal to 3. Please let me know how can I start the ServerThread code only when there are 3 clients. What is possible solution there to run some specific code on receiving 3 clients information. I also need to code a timer on mcqs when I asked a question to user if on that time user doesn't submitted his answer then next question will be asked to that user.

I haven't found any solution online for that.

Server Class

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Server {
    private static ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Mcq> mcqs = new ArrayList<>();
    ServerSocket serversocket;
    Socket client;
    int clientCount = 0;
    static int players = 0;
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public static void buildMCQs(){
        try {

            File fXmlFile = new File("questionaire.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("QuestionBank");
            Node nNode = nList.item(nList.getLength()-1);
            if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode;
                players = Integer.parseInt(eElement1.getAttribute("players"));
                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Question");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    mcqs.add(new Mcq());
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element eElement = (Element) node;
                        mcqs.get(i).setId(Integer.parseInt(eElement.getAttribute("id")));
                        mcqs.get(i).setAnswer(Integer.parseInt(eElement.getAttribute("answerid")));
                    }
                }
            }
            NodeList nodeList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("text");
            for (int j = 0; j < nodeList1.getLength(); j++) {
                Node node1 = nodeList1.item(j);
                if(node1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement2 = (Element) node1;
                    mcqs.get(j).setTitle(eElement2.getTextContent());
                }
            }
            NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("option");
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < nodeList2.getLength(); j++) {
                Node node2 = nodeList2.item(j);
                if(node2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement3 = (Element) node2;
                    if(count <= mcqs.size()){
                        mcqs.get(count).setOption(eElement3.getTextContent());
                    }
                    if(j == 3){
                        count = 1;
                    }
                    if(j == 7){
                        count = 2;
                    }
                    if(j == 11){
                        count = 3;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void start() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Connection Started...");
        //make connection to client on port specified
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(12345);

        //accept connection from client
        while (true){
            client = serversocket.accept();
            clientCount++;
            ServerThread runnable = new ServerThread();
            pool.execute(runnable);
        }
    }
    public class ServerThread implements Runnable{
        DataInputStream input;
        DataOutputStream output;
        public void run(){
            try{
                System.out.println("New Client received...");
                //open buffered reader for reading data from client
                input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                output = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

                String greetings = "*** Welcome to our Game server ***";
                output.writeUTF(greetings);
//that's the wrong logic


                if(clientCount == 3) {
                    String promptFirstName = "Enter first name: ";
                    output.writeUTF(promptFirstName);
                    String firstName = input.readUTF(); //read1

                    String promptLastName = "Enter last name: ";
                    output.writeUTF(promptLastName);
                    String lastName = input.readUTF();

                    String promptAge = "Enter your age: ";
                    output.writeUTF(promptAge);
                    int age = Integer.parseInt(input.readUTF());
                    clients.add(new Client(firstName, lastName, age));

                    int points = 0;
                    output.writeUTF(String.valueOf(mcqs.size()));
                    output.writeUTF(String.valueOf(mcqs.get(0).getOptions().size()));

                    for (int i = 0; i < mcqs.size(); i++) {
                        try {
                            output.writeUTF(mcqs.get(i).getTitle());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < mcqs.get(i).getOptions().size(); j++) {
                            try {
                                output.writeUTF(mcqs.get(i).getOptions().get(j));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        try {
                            output.writeUTF("Answer: ");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            if (Integer.parseInt(input.readUTF()) == mcqs.get(i).getAnswer()) {
                                output.writeUTF("Right!");
                                points += 10;
                            } else {
                                output.writeUTF("Wrong!");
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    output.writeUTF(String.valueOf(points));
                }

            }catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        buildMCQs();
        Server server = new Server();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client class

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream input;
    DataOutputStream output;

    public Client(){

    }
    public Client(String firstName, String lastName, int age){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public void startClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

        //Create socket connection
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        String greetings = input.readUTF();
        System.out.println(greetings);

        String firstName = input.readUTF();
        System.out.println(firstName);
        setFirstName(scanner.nextLine());
        output.writeUTF(getFirstName()); //write1

        //prompt for user name
        String lastName = input.readUTF();
        System.out.println(lastName);
        setLastName(scanner.nextLine());
        output.writeUTF(getLastName()); //write1

        //prompt for age
        String age = input.readUTF();
        System.out.println(age);
        setAge(scanner.nextInt());
        output.writeUTF(String.valueOf(getAge()));

        int questions = Integer.parseInt(input.readUTF());
        int options = Integer.parseInt(input.readUTF());
        for (int i = 0; i < questions; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(input.readUTF());
            for (int j = 0; j < options; j++) {
                System.out.println(j+1+"."+input.readUTF());
            }
            System.out.println(input.readUTF());
            output.writeUTF(String.valueOf(scanner.nextInt()));
            System.out.println(input.readUTF());
        }
        System.out.println("Points Scored: "+ input.readUTF()+"/30");


    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Client client = new Client();
        try {
            client.startClient();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

XML FILE

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <QuestionBank players="3">
        <Question id="1" answerid="1">
            <text>Who invented the BALLPOINT PEN?</text>
            <answers>
                <option id="1">Biro Brothers</option>
                <option id="2">Waterman Brothers</option>
                <option id="3">Bicc Brothers</option>
                <option id="4">Write Brothers</option>
            </answers>
        </Question>
        <Question id="2" answerid="1">
            <text>In which decade was the first solid state integrated circuit demonstrated?</text>
            <answers>
                <option id="1">1950s</option>
                <option id="2">1960s</option>
                <option id="3">1970s</option>
                <option id="4">1980s</option>
            </answers>
        </Question>
        <Question id="3" answerid="4">
            <text>Which scientist discovered the radioactive element radium?</text>
            <answers>
                <option id="1">Isaac Newton</option>
                <option id="2">Albert Einstein</option>
                <option id="3">Benjamin Franklin</option>
                <option id="4">Marie Curie</option>
            </answers>
        </Question>
    </QuestionBank>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [how to ask]. In particular, you will have more chances of receiving good answers if you create a [mcve]. There are a lot of extra stuff in your code that have nothing to do with the question you are asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of socket clients connected to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191185/number-of-socket-clients-connected-to-server)

Comment: @jrook, fix your template - "[how to ask]" was supposed to be a link I believe.

Comment: The correct link is : [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)